# IPv4 only host on a dual stack environment

Tags: ip, ipv4, ipv6, protocol-theory, ipv6-transition

I am looking into migrating to IPv6 at my company. Our plan is to dual-stack everything for now, however, we have a couple of local servers that are IPv4 capable only. The rest of our network will be dual-stacked.

Is a NAT64 device absolutely required or will the dual-stack hosts be able to access the IPv4 only server using IPv4 network automatically?

Comment: You could also decommission the antique hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do that anytime soon due to funds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dual-stacked hosts can easily get to either IPv4 or IPv6 devices. You need to make sure that DNS is correctly set up. Such a host will probably default to IPv6 if there is a AAAA record, so you do not want that for the IPv4-only devices. You can ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) about setting that up correctly.

Comment: So a NAT64 device will only be needed if we move to an IPv6 only network, correct?

Comment: Yes, but be careful with translation. It is like an opiate. It has its uses, but it is easy to get hooked, and then you can get into all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily we don't need NAT for IPv4, and therefore, I don't have as much knowledge of it as I'd like, so trying to figure out NAT64 has been gruesome. Dual-stack will give me some more time to figure out NAT64 for if/when the time comes.